# can I use react native to build a mobile app with Django rest api?

Tags: react-native

I am newbie to react native. Recently I am thinking of building a cross-platform mobile app. I am already developing backend rest API in Django. Is it possible to use react native in this case ? If not, what would my other choices ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is. You have to use `fetch` in order to use your API. The most important thing is that your API returns JSON (ideally) or another response that can be handled by Javascript (HTML, XML, ...).

Here you have a tiny example about how to fetch data from your API in React Native.

```
 fetch('http://your-django-api-url.com/endpoint?query=id')  
 .then((response) => {
     return response.json()
 })
```

More information here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html